# MSSQL: Select into: varchar(max) to date - Can't get it to work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a project to load legacy data from source tables into target tables in MSSQL.
I can't use SSIS due to company restrictions so I need to use T-SQL and preferably in a stored procedure.

I have the legacy tables containing only varchar(max) fields and a target table which has all the right datatypes.

Theres a couple of the source tables that contain date data which is stored in varchar(max) and which needs to be loaded into date format fields. This preferably needs to happen via 'select into' types of queries in SQL Server 2008

What I've done is a simple query:                                                      `INSERT INTO [SRC].[TargetTable] 
        (
            col1,
            col2,
            col3,
            col4,
            col5,
            col6,
            col7,
            col8,
            col9,
            col10
        )
        SELECT 
            accr_nr,
            address,
            number,
            addition,
            postalcode,
            city,
            close_date,
            personnr,
            discount,
            clientnr
        FROM [STG].[oldtable]`

Thanks!

close_date contains varchar data in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: Post some code you attempted. What errors are you getting?

Comment: (1) You don't use `select into` with existing tables; (2) Show code that you have tried in your question; (3) Show sample data in your question.

Comment: 1. Are you going to very frequently transfer data. 2.No doubt,you need to do lot of datatype validation.like suppose one row is not valid date then what will happen ?will it skip that row or will it skip whole transaction ?Most probably you will need IsDate,IsNumeric etc.3.Show your query.

Comment: Please post the simple query and explain in what way it does not work.  The more detial you can provide the more likely it is you will recieve a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Using convert(datetime, varcharfield, 110)varcharfield gives me the following error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 0):

The simple query ..

```
--SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee ON

 INSERT INTO  DemoDB1.dbo.Employee(MayBeIdentityId,Name,close_date)
 SELECT MayBeIdentityId, 
        Name,
        CONVERT(datetime,close_dateVarColumn)close_date 
 From DemoDB2.Dbo.Employee

--SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee OFF
```

**Note**: Both db should reside on `same server` and `user must have both db access`

Comment: Thanks Moumit but my case needs varchar(max) -> date

Comment: yeah I know but it gives me the error posted in my org question (The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.)

Comment: Thanks @Moumit. But trying the updated query still gives me: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.